# How to apply WHEN-CASE or if-else condition in solr lucene query

Tags: solr, lucene

I want apply similar query as below in solr search

```
(case when a>b then start>[NOW-3DAYS TO *] else start>[NOW-7DAYS TO *]) and field1=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
start>if(a>b,[NOW-3DAYS TO *],[NOW-7DAYS TO *]) and field1=true
```